# Shell script for iterating over a folder tree and copy sub folders files

Tags: shell

I'm trying to create a script which will iterate over a folder. In that folder there are a lot of subprojects.
I need to go to every subproject and copy `src` folder to the same folder but in a external one.

```
find ~/project/ \( -name 'src' \) -delete
```

This is what I have for deleting old `src` folders from every external folders but I do not know how to copy the new ones.
EDIT:
I draw on my notebook the structure. Bycp i mean repleace.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackExchange. Please edit your question to include the directory structure at the beginning, as well as the expected directory structure after running the `find` command.

Comment: This can probably be done with a simple `find` command, but I'm having a hard time understanding where you want the `src` dirs to be copied to. Can you show an example of a before/after directory structure to explain what you have in mind

Comment: i have edited my question.

Comment: 11/10 for using paper, but can you convert to text, for our blind users.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor
I want to, but i do not how.

Comment: I don't see much change, just removel of the top level directory. It the new-one initially empty?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for contributing! But please, don't post images of text ([read this for reasons why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)).  In this case, you could, for example, use the `tree` utility for creating a text representation of a directory structure.

Comment: This definitely looks a bit 'homeworky'.....but do you need to `iterate over` the directories or `just copy the src`.....?

Comment: @bu5hman
I need only to copy the src in the same external folder as show on the picture

Answer (score 4):

From the *parent* of project you can use a lovely backup tool called rsync:

`rsync -av project/ .`

the above will copy all sub-directories to the parent. If you only want a named subdirectory, then it's a bit more complex, you will need to run this from *within* the **project/** directory:

`find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "src" -exec rsync -aRv {} .. \;`

What we are doing here is finding your **src** subdirectories and passing them to rsync, crucially including the *R* flag, which tells rsync to maintain relative pathnames in the target.

Comment: This is beautiful. Add `--delete` if target folders existed before with different content which regarding the question, I assume this is the case.

Comment: Why not just `mv`?

Comment: @siloko
The idea is to move only the src/ folders, not copy the entire ones, cause in the way i will loose a lot of data.

Comment: Both assume the src files are alone.....

Comment: Or a little more specific `rsync -a --include '/project*' --include '**src/***' --exclude '*' ./old.one/ new.one`